# Need some Help Understanding Code Signing

Tags: .net, windows, code-signing-certificate

I am attempting to understand and use **[MS Sign Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe#sign)** to sign an exe file with a self-sign certificate I generated in another Visual Studio program.

I want to self-sign in the ***`SignedFileTEST.exe`*** outside Visual Studio.
I stumbled around and found some sample scripts and have no luck with them.

I am trying from the command prompt with the following:

```bat
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\"

signtool.exe sign /f  "C:\TESTsign.pfx" /p 1230Carlos# "C:\Projects\SignedFileTEST.exe"
```

> **I get no errors.**
> **It just seems to do nothing.**

---

Any help will be most appreciated
Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: What's the return code of `signtool.exe`? Unless you got a non-zero value, there simply isn't any error.

Comment: What happens if you run just `"signtool.exe"` on a command line? Does it show anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `/fd` option to the command line.

From the documentation :

*[The Windows 10 SDK, Windows 10 HLK, Windows 10 WDK and Windows 10 ADK builds 20236 and later require specifying the digest algorithm.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)*

[*The SignTool sign command requires the `/fd` file digest algorithm and the `/td` timestamp digest algorithm option to be specified during signing and timestamping, respectively.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)

> An error (error code 1) will be thrown if `/fd` is not specified during
> signing and if `/td` is not specified during timestamping.

- So the correct anser would be:

```
signtool.exe sign /f  "C:\TESTsign.pfx" /p 1230Carlos# /fd SHA256 "C:\Projects\SignedFileTEST.exe"
```